# Pandoc: 'The picture can't be displayed' error shown for some images in .docx file after converting from .md

Tags: ms-word, docx, pandoc

I'm trying to convert our Git Wiki from .md to .docx files and some images are not displayed in the resulting Word file. It seems that whether the image will be shown depends on the URL and not the image itself.

Example of image references in an original .md file that would result in an error in .docx:

```
![irr](https://git.{project}.com/pb/{project}/-/wikis/uploads/addf556fa0eaea08b97955c5da7b6229/02_01_Funds___IRR.png)
```

But the same image uploaded to a different service works fine with the following reference:

```
![irr_imgur](https://i.imgur.com/{image_id}.png)
```

Also, slightly different address on the same Git Wiki works fine too:

```
![vc-benchmarking-fund](https://git.{project}.com/pb/{project}/uploads/06befbe869ba02844f344f86adc1f1f4/vc-benchmarking-fund.png)
```

Pandoc shows no errors. With verbose logging on it shows the following:

```
[INFO] Fetching https://git.{project}.com/pb/{project}/-/wikis/uploads/addf556fa0eaea08b97955c5da7b6229/02_01_Funds___IRR.png...
[INFO] Fetching https://i.imgur.com/{image_id}.png...
```

But the first image is shown as an error, and the second is displayed fine. Errorred images content don't seem to be included in docx file.

The command I use for conversion:

```
pandoc C:\GitWiki\Mediator\Business-Domain\Funds\Advanced-Search-Funds-IRR-Search-functionality.md -s -o C:\GitWiki\Migrated\Business-Domain\Funds\Advanced-Search-Funds-IRR-Search-functionality.docx
```

Is there a way to fix it? Is it a specific part of the URL that causes this issue?

P.S. Sorry for the placeholders, I'm under NDA

Comment: It seems that pandoc manages to fetch the image, but then it won't display properly. My first guess is that the server sends an incorrect MIME type for the problematic image. Can you test with `curl -I https://PROBLEMATIC_IMAGE.png` and report the `Content-Type` in the response?

Comment: @Anton Argunov: I experienced the same issue for this image https://docs.aws.amazon.com/images/rekognition/latest/dg/images/technical-cue.png

When I used the URL in the markdown I got the error "The picture can't be displayed".

When I downloaded the image locally and then used the local file in the markdown, the PPTX had the image in it and worked perfectly.

I ran the curl -I command and did not see anything unusual. 

curl -I https://docs.aws.amazon.com/images/rekognition/latest/dg/images/technical-cue.png